# Is There a Convinient Method for org.mockito.Mockito.times(1)?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, refactoring

I'm searching for an officially provided method to replace the last line of...

```
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.then;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;

// ...

Runnable mock = mock(Runnable.class);
then(mock).should(times(1)).run();
```

...with something *shorter* like:

```
then(mock).should(once()).callMethod();
```

Why *shorter*? Because IntelliJ's usually helpful feature shows the parameter's name, resulting in many long code lines:

```
then(mock).should(times(wantedNumberOfInvocations: 1)).callMethod();
```

I know that I can easily write such a function, but then I'd either have to duplicate it for a couple of workspace projects or otherwise to introduce a new module, which seems to be overdone to me.

Would be nice if you could point out something like `Mockito.atLeastOnce()` for `Mockito.atLeast(1)`, just without the `atLeast` part :-) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other alternative is to use simple `should()`, which is an alias for single invocation:

```
then(mock).should().callMethod();
```

Comment: I wrote a little test to prove it and it worked great. Nice one, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such method. Just declare your own if you want one.

```
private static VerificationMode once()
{
    return Mockito.times(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
Mockito.calls(1).someMethod()
```